# Does python-memcache use consistent hashing?

Tags: python, memcached

I'm using the python-memcache library, and I'm wondering if anyone knows if consistent hashing is used by that client as of 1.44.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a quick view into the source code: No it does not. It uses `server = hash_key % len(servers)` and round-robin if offline/full servers are encountered.

Comment: Yeah my bad, I should have viewed the source myself. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you need something like that you might be interested in [hash_ring](http://amix.dk/blog/viewEntry/19367)