# Consistent Hashing in python-memcache

Tags: python, memcached, hash, consistent-hashing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does python-memcache use consistent hashing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926814/does-python-memcache-use-consistent-hashing)

Does python-memcached support consistent hashing? I found a few threads about this but most of them were more than 2 years old.

Cheers